# Can't use two "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying"

Tags: xcode, memory-management, xcode4, avaudioplayer

Can you please tell me how to fix this? I want to release two different `AVAudioPlayer` when they finish playing, but separately.

Here's my code:

**.h File**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
     NSString          *path;
}

- (IBAction)Short:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)BeatLong:(id)sender;
```

**.m File**

```
AVAudioPlayer   *media;
AVAudioPlayer   *media2;

- (IBAction)Short:(id)sender
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Short" ofType:@"wav"];
    media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [media setDelegate:self];
    [media play];
}

- (IBAction)Beat:(id)sender
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Beat" ofType:@"mp3"];
    media2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [media2 setDelegate:self];
    [media2 play];
}
```

[image: .m]

(Open the image in a new tab to see it better ^^,)

Comment: I've added more code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nay, that's illegal on the grounds of the language.

You have to distinguish the different players according to the AVAudioPlayer * pointer 
submitted with the message.

If you just want to release it, just write

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)aPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag
{ 
    [aPlayer release]; 
}
```

and you're done and illegal too, since you don't own aPlayer.

But a better solution would be to detect which audio player you own and release it.

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)aPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag
{ 
    if ( aPlayer == self.media )
        [self.media release];
    else if ( aPlayer == self.media2 ) 
        [self.media2 release];
    // other players cannot be released, since we don't know anything about their owner.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but XCode says: Property 'media' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Comment: That's because @Wizz's second sample code assumes media and media2 are retained properties, which is probably how you should implement them. In your sample code, they're just global variables.

Comment: Yes, it is a lot easier since retain-releases are partially managed by the accessors generated when you @synthesize them.